# Are Fallout 3 savegames on the PS3 compatible with the GOTY version?

Tags: ps3, fallout-3

This question is very similar but it's specific to the PC version: [Can I use Fallout 3 savegames in Fallout 3 GOTY?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/8033/use-fallout-3-savegames-in-fallout-3-goty)

I have the original Fallout 3 disk for my PS3 and I'd like to get the GOTY version. Will my existing savegames be compatible with the new disk?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to Fallout 3's [website](http://fallout.bethsoft.com/eng/games/f3-faq.php), It will work fine.

**Will my existing Fallout 3 saves be compatible with Fallout 3 Game of the Year Edition?**

> Yes, existing Fallout 3 saves will work fine, though you can also
>   choose to start a new character.